# SignalR 2.0 error after updating through Nuget

Tags: signalr

I've updated SignalR to 2.0 in an ASPNET MVC 4.0 application and now I'm receiving the following error:

**Counter 'Message Bus Messages Published Total' does not exist in the specified Category**

The error is thrown on

```
app.MapSignalR();
```

This is the code I'm using now in the Startup class (previously I used RegisterHubs.

```
public static class Startup
{
    public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var signalrDependencyContainer = new WindsorContainer().Install(new HubsInstaller());
        var signalrDependency = new SignalrDependencyResolver(signalrDependencyContainer.Kernel);
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = signalrDependency;
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an partial extract of the code as requested.

This is what I get when installing the counters

```
PM> signalr ipc
SignalR Utility Version: 1.1.0.0
Installing performance counters...
  Connections Connected
  Connections Reconnected
  Connections Disconnected
  Connections Current
  Connection Messages Received Total
  Connection Messages Sent Total
  Connection Messages Received/Sec
  Connection Messages Sent/Sec
  Message Bus Messages Received Total
  Message Bus Messages Received/Sec
  Scaleout Message Bus Messages Received/Sec
  Messages Bus Messages Published Total
  Messages Bus Messages Published/Sec
  Message Bus Subscribers Current
  Message Bus Subscribers Total
  Message Bus Subscribers/Sec
  Message Bus Allocated Workers
  Message Bus Busy Workers
  Message Bus Topics Current
  Errors: All Total
  Errors: All/Sec
  Errors: Hub Resolution Total
  Errors: Hub Resolution/Sec
  Errors: Hub Invocation Total
  Errors: Hub Invocation/Sec
  Errors: Tranport Total
  Errors: Transport/Sec
  Scaleout Streams Total
  Scaleout Streams Open
  Scaleout Streams Buffering
  Scaleout Errors Total
  Scaleout Errors/Sec
  Scaleout Send Queue Length

Performance counters installed!
```

**StartupOwin.cs**

```
using org.app.Ui.Web.App_Start;
using Microsoft.Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(StartupOwin), "Configuration")]
namespace org.app.Ui.Web.App_Start
{
    using Owin;

    public class StartupOwin
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            org.app.Ui.Web.App_Start.StartupSignalR.ConfigureSignalR(app);
        }
    }
}
```

**StartupSignalR.cs**

```
namespace org.app.Ui.Web.App_Start
{
    using Castle.Windsor;
    using org.app.Ui.Web.Infrastructure;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
    using Owin;

    public static class StartupSignalR
    {
        public static void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
            {
                Resolver = new SignalrDependencyResolver(
                    new WindsorContainer()
                    .Install(new HubsInstaller()).Kernel)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**HubNewHandler.cs**

```
namespace org.app.Ui.Web.Hubs
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Timers;

    using Castle.MicroKernel;
    using Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle;
    using Castle.Windsor;
    using org.app.Data.Contracts;
    using org.app.Data.Model;

    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

    public class HubNewHandler : IHubNewHandler
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
        private DateTime lastDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        readonly private IKernel kernel;

        public HubNewHandler(IKernel kernel)
        {
            this.kernel = kernel;
        }

        public void StartTimer()
        {
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SendNewMessage);
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
        }

        public void SendNewMessage(object state, ElapsedEventArgs elapsedEventArgs)
        {
            using (kernel.BeginScope())
            {
                var gdpUow = kernel.Resolve<IGdpUow>();

                var gdpTesisConfigurationsRecord = gdpUow.GdpConfigurations.GetByPredicate(a => a.Description.Equals("LastDateTimeMessagesCheck")).SingleOrDefault();

                if (gdpTesisConfigurationsRecord == null)
                {
                    gdpTesisConfigurationsRecord = new GdpConfiguration
                            {
                                Description = "LastDateTimeMessagesCheck",
                                DateTimeValue = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()
                            };
                    gdpUow.GdpConfigurations.Add(gdpTesisConfigurationsRecord);
                }

                var lastMessagesDateTimeCheck = gdpTesisConfigurationsRecord.DateTimeValue;
                var messagesList = GetShowableMessagesList(gdpUow, lastMessagesDateTimeCheck);

                // Get a hub context for ServerHub
                var serverHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ServerHub>();

                // Send a message to all the clients
                serverHub.Clients.All.addNewMessagesToMap(messagesList, false);

                gdpTesisConfigurationsRecord.DateTimeValue = elapsedEventArgs.SignalTime.ToUniversalTime();
                gdpUow.GdpConfigurations.Update(gdpTesisConfigurationsRecord);
                gdpUow.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ServerHub.cs**

```
namespace org.app.Ui.Web.Hubs
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Data.Contracts;
    using Data.Model;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

    public class ServerHub : Hub
    {
        public IGdpUow Uow { get; set; }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
            var connectionId = Guid.Parse(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnConnected();
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected()
        {
            var connectionId = Guid.Parse(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnDisconnected();
        }

        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
            var connectionId = Guid.Parse(Context.ConnectionId);
            return base.OnReconnected();
        }

        public void GetAllMessages()
        {
            var messagesList = Uow.Messages.GetAll();
            Clients.All.addNewMessagesToMap(messagesList, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?
Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing a different version of Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils.  I got this error after installing version 1.1.2 of the utils.  I uninstalled that, and installed version 2.1.1:

```
Install-Package microsoft.aspnet.SignalR.Utils -version 2.1.1
```

Then I ran the command again:

```
signalr.exe ipc
```

Finally, I restarted my application and it worked.  The problem seems to be that one version uses "***Messages*** Bus Messages Published Total" and the other uses "***Message*** Bus Messages Published Total" (*Note the "s" is missing in "Message" in the second one*).  [See more information here (how's your Korean?)](http://www.sysnet.pe.kr/Default.aspx?mode=2&sub=0&detail=1&pageno=0&wid=1727&rssMode=1&wtype=0)

Answer (score 1):

For SignalR 2.0 , add the Owin references.

(Note: I don't know your application name, change *yourapplicationname* (mentioned twice in the code) to the name of your application.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(yourapplicationname.Startup))]
namespace yourapplicationname
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var signalrDependencyContainer = new WindsorContainer().Install(new HubsInstaller());
            var signalrDependency = new SignalrDependencyResolver(signalrDependencyContainer.Kernel);
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = signalrDependency;
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Already did that, and it's entering into the Configuration method, but the error still happens. I've also installed SignalR Utilities and ran signalr ipc to install the counters...but I can't understand why it says it is installing the version 1.1.0.0 and not then newer one 2.0 despite I've downloaded and installed it via Nuget.

Comment: @polonskyg open an empty project and install signalr 2.0 from nuget, then copy paste your codes into the new project. I think you still have somewhere some codes which require version 1.0 dependency.

Comment: I've added the code in the original post.
I've created a new project and there the Signal.Sample project downloaded from Nuget, seems to be working. But not mine.